# node : send value from on page to another?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js

in php i knew about session and url to send value to another page. for example

```
public/ 
    index.php
         profile/
            editProfile.php
            viewprofile.php
```

in index php i want to call viewprofile.php and send value from index.php so viewprofile.php can receive the value.. i use ($_GET / $_REQUEST / $_POST) so i success get value from index.php

for related of my description above,i want to ask, how i achieve that, send value from one page to another page use nodejs (without express) ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using templating languages like JADE or DUST.For example,
In your routehandler function you can call the dust file as follows:

var user=request.session.name;

response.render('viewprofile',{user:user});

where viewprofile is a dust file where you can access the user variable as {user}.

check https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial for DUST tutorial